# How to write a method using strand sort

Tags: c#, console-application, mergesort

I admit, this is a homework for my project and i came here because i don't know how to do it.

**What i have to do**

Write a method editUsingStrands(), which returns the growing field of integers arranged. Returned field should be the same size and with the same values ​​as stored in the specified field. The algorithm should not exceed O (n3) growth of complexity.

I have done this using LIST, but i just found out  is not allowed, and so are not any complex functions like Sort, RemoveAt, Count...(dunno if all are complex functions, but i know they are not allowed).

Can somebody help me re-create it without using LIST and those functions?

Thank you very much!

**My code**

```
static int[] editUsingStrands(int[] field)
    {
        List<int> organizedField = new List<int>();
        List<int> xField = new List<int>(field);

        while(xField.Count > 0)
        {
            List<int> sublist = new List<int>();

            sublist.Add(xField[0]);
            xField.RemoveAt(0);

            for(int i=0; i< xField.Count; i++)
            {
                if(xField[i] > sublist[sublist.Count-1])
                {
                    sublist.Add(xField[i]);
                    xField.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }

            organizedField = new List<int>(mergeTogether(organizedField.ToArray(), sublist.ToArray()));
        }

        return organizedField.ToArray();
```

### }

```
static int[] mergeTogether(int[] field1, int[] field2)
    {
        List<int> organizedMergedField = new List<int>();
        int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0;

        while ((counter1 + counter2) < (field1.Length + field.Length))
        {
            if (field1.Length > counter1)
            {
                if (field2.Length > counter2)
                {
                    if (field1[counter1] < field2[counter2])
                    {
                        organizedMergedField.Add(field1[counter1]);
                        counter1++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        organizedMergedField.Add(field2[counter2]);
                        counter2++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    organizedMergedField.Add(field1[counter1]);
                    counter1++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                organizedMergedField.Add(field2[counter2]);
                counter2++;
            }
        }

        return organizedMergedField.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Consider a [LinkedList](http://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strand_sort)

Comment: Of course, only if you are allowed to use LinkedList.